# how to Mapping input properties and getting their values in Item display template?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, search-results, display-template

I have the following list:

[image]

type of my columns are regular column.  I want Customize Display Template for Content By **Search result** Web Part ([Link01](http://SharePoint%202013%20Customize%20Display%20Template%20for%20Content%20By%20Search%20Web%20Part) and [Link02](http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/))
but pictureLink, description, pictureLink and AbstractLink attribute return null, with following commands:

> var pictureLink =$getItemValue(ctx, "PictureLink");
>
> var description =$getItemValue(ctx, "Description");
>
> var pictureLink =$getItemValue(ctx, "PictureLink");
>
> var AbstractLink =$getItemValue(ctx, "PictureLink"); and so.

but with ***var Title =$getItemValue(ctx, "Title");*** command, title return correct value.

how to Mapping input properties and getting their values in Item display template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to change the way search results are displayed in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj613136.aspx)

about the naming conventions for automatically created crawled properties and managed properties ([How to display values from custom managed properties in search results](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/11/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-results-option-1.aspx#FindMPName))

Comment: Link only answers are not how we like it here, please add more details to your answer to make it useful even if /when the links break

Answer (score 2):

When working with a Display Template you have to request Managed Properties from the Context of the current item. The general process is:

1. Crawl content
2. Map crawled properties to Managed Properties
3. Crawl Content again
4. Create a new Display Template (often by copying an existing
   template)
5. Add a reference to your custom managed property in the display
   template to the ManagedPropertyMapping attribute
6. Create a placeholder in the body of the display template for the
   managed property using syntax like:

   ctx.CurrentItem.MyManagedProperty

I wrote up a full walk through here: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

There are other posts on my site for debugging as well as a link to my session video from SCP14 on Display Templates and Query Rules.

Comment: do not Map crawled properties to Managed Properties(Option 2),What can I do?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: how to Map crawled properties to Managed Properties?